# ldap configuration in airflow when rbac is True

Tags: ldap, airflow, rbac

I was configuring ldap in airflow.
Followed this documentation here - https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html

webserver_config.py

```
import os
from airflow import configuration as conf
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = conf.get('core', 'SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN')

CSRF_ENABLED = True

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP

AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"
# AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Viewer"

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = 'ldaps://ldap:636/'
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=domain,DC=net"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = 'CN=admin,DC=domain,DC=net'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'password'
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = 'sAMAccountName'
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False
```

for running ldap container i used osixia/docker-openldap

but i run webserver and try to login it gives `Invalid login. Please try again.` No matter what id password i gave.

When not using ldap it is able to login with the user i created using airflow cli create_user

I don't know if i am doing everything right. There is no good documentation/article with the steps.
Can someone help me on this? THANKS!!!

Comment: dot in case you resolve it

Comment: Is their any resolution to this error ? I'm also getting exact same error while adding LDAP Auth to Airflow 2.0